# Adding value to pandas dataframe with multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data = d)
list = [(0,3,1,5), ...]
def function(x):
    df.loc[x[0],"col1"] = x[1]
    df.loc[x[2],"col2"] = x[3]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(function, list)
df.to_csv("tset.csv")
```

Finally, the output of the dataframe is empty. I know for dictionary we can use multiprocessing.Manager().dict to share memory. But this can't be applied to pandas dataframe. Is there any easy way to put the dataframe into shared memory?

Comment: No, there isn't an easy way to use a shared-memory pandas data-frame. Why are you using `multiprocessing` for this anyway? What exactly are you trying to do? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I updated my code. Because I have a very large dataframe I would like to access it's loc and make changes to its value. If I use the for loop it will take quick a long time, so I am thinking to use multiprocessing package to do the job.

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way.  Your first step has been "slow code using `for` loops."  Your second step should not be "using multiprocessing," but rather "fast vectorized code in a single thread."  We can help you optimize if you tell us exactly what the real code does.